# Criação de trigger que salve informação em arquivo

Tags: postgresql, trigger

Preciso salvar em um arquivo TXT todos os códigos de fechamentos efetuados num banco de dados PostgreSQL.

A tabela **fechamentos** tem os seguintes campos:

```
codigo |    data    | nome
-------|------------|---------
1      | 2019-08-01 | Castor
2      | 2019-08-03 | Atlas
3      | 2019-08-05 | Nova
```

Quando for inserido um novo registro preciso que o código desse registro seja copiado para um arquivo com o nome codigos.txt.

Sei que existe o comando **copy** do PostgreSQL e que quando executo ele, o arquivo é criado corretamente com o código, mas a cada execução do comando a informação anterior do arquivo é sobrescrita e eu preciso que cada novo código fique numa nova linha do arquivo, ou seja, mantendo o resultado anterior da execução.

Segue o comando que utilizei para fazer os testes com o **copy** (*A query é só de teste*):

```
COPY (SELECT MAX(codigo) FROM fechamentos) TO 'C:\Leitura\codigos.txt'
```

Como posso criar essa trigger?

Comment: não seria possível fazer isso via aplicação? o ideal é sempre que possível evitar triggers.

Comment: @danilo, não, a aplicação é de terceiros.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11056546/output-to-file-from-pgsql-trigger acho que você terá que pedir para a comunidade adicionar essa funcionalidade numa nova versão do postgresql

Comment: Mas pode ser usada uma procedure que execute o copy!

Comment: https://tada.github.io/pljava/use/hello.html você pode tentar chamar um batch via pljava na trigger

Comment: Se quiser manipular arquivos em alguma linguagem procedimental em um SGBD PostgreSQL pesquise por UNTRUSTED Languages.

Comment: https://raghavt.blog/install-pl-java-1-5-2-in-postgresql-11/ para usar pljava você vai precisar compilar e executar o instalador dele que copia as bibliotecas no teu postgresql, reiniciar o postregsql, faça tudo isso num servidor de testes antes, teste bem, tenha todo um plano de contingencia e de fallback quando for fazer em produção.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não tenho conhecimento se no postgresql é possível apenas editar um arquivo,
a lógica seria ler o arquivo atual, adicionar a informação nova e escreve-lo novamente:

utilizei um txt de exemplo, com o seguinte conteúdo:

> 'D:\teste\1.txt'

```
0;maria
1;joao
```

Crio uma tabela temporária que irá armazenar o conteúdo do arquivo:

```
create temp table txt
(
id varchar,
nome varchar
);
```

Carrego o arquivo para a tabela temporária:

```
copy txt from 'd:\teste\1.txt' with CSV DELIMITER ';';
```

Escrevo o arquivo novamente, com a nova informação:

```
copy 
(select id,nome from txt
union ALL
select '9','novo registro')
to 'd:\teste\1.txt' with CSV DELIMITER ';';
```

Apago a tabela temporária:

```
drop table txt;
```

Resultado:

```
0;maria
1;joao
9;novo registro
```

> Obs: Utilizei union ALL pois no exemplo pode repetir os valores (se ficar executando várias vezes, vai adicionando `9;novo registro` ao final do arquivo)
>
> Obs: Seu arquivo de texto não parece estar em um formato para ser lido com facilidade pelo banco, prefira formatos padrões, utilizando delimitadores.
>
> Obs: Cuidado com o tamanho do arquivo, rs

**Lógica explicada acima, vamos à criação da trigger:**

Primeiro, cria-se uma function que será executada quando a trigger for executada:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.escreve_fechamento (
)
RETURNS trigger AS
$body$
    BEGIN

        create temp table txt ( id varchar,nome varchar );
        copy txt from 'd:\teste\1.txt' with CSV DELIMITER ';';
        insert into txt (id,nome) values (new.codigo,new.nome);
        copy (select id,nome from txt) to 'd:\teste\1.txt' with CSV DELIMITER ';';
        drop table txt;

    RETURN NULL;
    END;
$body$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
VOLATILE
CALLED ON NULL INPUT
SECURITY INVOKER
COST 100;
```

Criar a trigger que será executada após cada INSERT:

```
CREATE TRIGGER tg_escreve_fechamento AFTER INSERT
ON public.fechamento FOR EACH ROW 
EXECUTE PROCEDURE public.escreve_fechamento();
```

Testar:

```
insert into fechamento (id,nome) values (999,'Novo Fechamento');
```

> Obs: Dentro da sintaxe plpgsql não foi possível fazer um select com union e os dados passados na trigger, então fiz um insert na tabela temporária para então escrever no arquivo.

Comment: Entendi que sua dúvida é sobre ler / escrever o arquivo, e não na criação da trigger, correto ?

Comment: Também não sei como criar a trigger. :( Pode editar a pergunta.

Comment: Admito que estou pedindo demais! =( Se não puder não tem problema. Desde já agradeço!

Comment: deu certo ? @LaércioLopes

Comment: Desculpa, não vi que alterou a resposta. Vou testar sim! Muito obrigado!